# How do I know what key to play in?

Tags: key, saxophone

so i've been playing the Tenor Sax for a bit now. I'll download some sheet music or things along that line off the internet to practice, only sometimes it just doesn't sound right. Like for example, one note will sound like the right one but the next will sound completely different. Any advice?

Comment: The sheet music tells you what key to play in.  However, you will need music transposed for tenor sax.

Comment: More information is needed to answer your question. The problem could be that the music you're downloading is itself incorrect (quite common with internet downloads), it could that you're mis-reading the note, or mis-playing the note either because of fingering or embouchure.

Comment: The big issue I have trying to suss out this question is that it's not clear how you've arrived at the conclusion of the key being incorrect, nor what kind of error it is and how to approach the problem.

Comment: @Edward - playing by oneself, if the music is written properly, it should all come out 'in tune'. Albeit possibly in the 'wrong' key - whatever that is!

Answer (score 1):

It has been known that stuff on the 'net isn't always accurate!

There's also the possibility you haven't taken the *key signature* into account.

There's also the possibility that it's your own mistakes, touching the wrong keys on the sax.

Answering the header directly - you look at the key signature - the sharps or flats at the beginning of each line, and apply them to the appropriate notes - in all octaves, all through. That puts you in the written key, which will be transposed so others playing along will also sound like they're in that same key.

Also make sure your sax is tuned to concert pitch. Usually, a B♭ note will be the one to check to.

Answer (score 1):

There could be several reasons your playing doesn't sound right:

- the music you downloaded might have mistakes.
- the music you have might not be transposed for tenor sax. The notes need to be transposed a whole tone higher. The key signature will have two more sharps (or two less flats).
- You might not be playing the notes correctly.
- there might be something wrong with your instrument.

Here's a good example of what it can sound like if you have these problems: